# C: srand does not influence random number generator

Tags: c, macos, random, srand

I have the following c code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  srand(time(NULL));
  printf("%d\n", (int)random());
  return 0;  
}
```

To my understanding, this should print a different random number every time I execute the program because the random seed is dependent of the system time.

But every time run the program, I get exactly the same output:

```
1804289383
```

I still get the same output when I put custom values as argument for srand:

```
srand(1);
```

Or

```
srand(12345);
```

Does anyone have an Idea why this happens? Maybe it is because of my operating system (Mac OS 10.10.3)? Or the compiler I use (gcc)?

Are there simple alternatives?

Comment: What is `random()`? Maybe it is decoupled from `srand()`? Or did you mean to use `rand()`? You need `srandom()` to set the seed for `random()`.

Comment: `srand` sets the seed for `rand`, not for `random`, for which there is `srandom`.

Comment: Thanks oehm. That seems to work. Would you like to write an answer so that I can give you points?

Comment: Even if you were using the correct seeding, you still have the problem that you're only generating one number. There's no such thing as "one randon number"--what you will have is a hash function of the seed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, your problem here is due to multiple way of making random numbers in C with the standard libraries.

Basically, there is two sets of functions to generate a random number :

> From the rand(3) manual:

```
   #include <stdlib.h>

   int rand(void);
   int rand_r(unsigned int *seedp);
   void srand(unsigned int seed);
```

> From the random(3) manual:

```
   #include <stdlib.h>

   long int random(void);

   void srandom(unsigned int seed);

   char *initstate(unsigned int seed, char *state, size_t n);
   char *setstate(char *state);
```

You should just pick the one that suit the best your need.
I invite you to further read those manuals for more information ;-)

Comment: `srand` and `rand` are defined by the ISO C standard, and exist in all C implementations. `srandom` and `random` are defined by POSIX, and are less portable (but are likely to be of higher quality than `srand` / `rand`).

Answer (score 6):

The standard random number generator in C is `rand()`, which can be seeded with `srand(seed)`.

There is a second random number generator, `random()`. This random generator can be seeded with the function `srandom(seed)`. (These two generators use separate states, even if they share the same implementation.)

So just pick the correct pair of seeding and RNG functions.